# join two tables and show all records

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables in Microsoft Access 2013:

tblService

```
PART_ID  SERV_DATE   SERV_REMARK  
A0001    11/1/2013   GOOD#1  
A0001    11/13/2013  GOOD#2  
A0001    11/25/2013  GOOD#3
```

tblWithdraw

```
PART_ID DRAWN_DATE  DRAWN_REASON  DRAWN_TO  
A0001   11/6/2013   PM            OW601  
A0001   11/20/2013  120 PM        OW603  
A0001   11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT   OW605
```

This is the result I want:

```
PART_ID SERV_DATE   SERV_REMARK  DRAWN_DATE  DRAWN_REASON  DRAWN_TO  
A0001   11/1/2013   GOOD#1       11/6/2013   PM            OW601  
A0001   11/13/2013  GOOD#2       11/20/2013  120 PM        OW603  
A0001   11/25/2013  GOOD#3       11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT   OW605
```

But I can get the result neither with `INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` nor `LEFT JOIN`. I tried with `FULL JOIN`, but system prompt me error:

> Syntax error in FROM clause

Below is my SQL.

```
SELECT 
  S.PART_ID, SERV_DATE, 
  SERV_REMARK, DRAWN_DATE, 
  DRAWN_REASON, DRAWN_TO
FROM 
  tblService AS S 
RIGHT JOIN 
  tblWithdraw AS W 
ON 
  S.PART_ID=W.PART_ID;
```

which shows the result as:

```
PART_ID SERV_DATE   SERV_REMARK  DRAWN_DATE  DRAWN_REASON  DRAWN_TO  
 A0001  11/1/2013     GOOD#1     11/6/2013        PM         OW601  
 A0001  11/13/2013    GOOD#2     11/6/2013        PM         OW601  
 A0001  11/25/2013    GOOD#3     11/6/2013        PM         OW601
 A0001  11/1/2013     GOOD#1     11/20/2013     120 PM       OW603  
 A0001  11/13/2013    GOOD#2     11/20/2013     120 PM       OW603  
 A0001  11/25/2013    GOOD#3     11/20/2013     120 PM       OW603
 A0001  11/1/2013     GOOD#1     11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT     OW605  
 A0001  11/13/2013    GOOD#2     11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT     OW605  
 A0001  11/25/2013    GOOD#3     11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT     OW605
```

Can somebody correct my SQL? Or any link to the right code? Thx!

Comment: How are you joining those records to get your expected result? Explain it in plain english, please.

Comment: How do tblService and tblWithdraw relate to one another? There is no foreign key in either table which will produce the join result you want. It appears the intent is to join a given row in tblService with the row in tblWithdraw whose DRAWN_DATE comes soonest after the SERV_DATE in the tblService row; is that correct? Also, what dialect of SQL is this?

Comment: I agree with Aaron.  Since Part_ID is identical in all rows, you need something else that makes them unique in order to join them.

Comment: Hi! Aaron. Thanks for you reply too. I'm a newbie in MS Access and SQL. I stuied examples from internet and tried to apply in my project. I'm sorry if I do not understand your post. You are right, in my project, the part will be serviced before it can be withdrawn. The transaction form will eventually shows all the information. Therefore, I have to create a query to join all the information from both the tables. But I can't get the result correctly. After googled, I think MS Access uses Access Jet-SQL.

Comment: Hi! Mosty. Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry if I don't make myself clear. I do not get my expected result. I have re-posted my result on the Question.

Comment: An important step of database design is to assign Primary Key and Foreign Key columns to tables. Unless you do this you get tables that can't be managed easily by SQL (amongst many other issues). Please review your table design before you attempt to build forms or write SQL.

Comment: Hi! Emmad. There is another table named tblPart that the PART_ID is the Primary Key which must be unique. Both PART_ID in tblService and tblWithdraw are related to the PART_ID in tblPart. I have created this in the Relationships. So both PART_ID in tblService and tblWithdraw are the Foreign Keys. Am I right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a unique relationship between your two tables and you need one.  You will have to restructure your tables (and how data is entered in to them), for example, so that they have a value that makes each instance of a part individual from others with the same `PART_ID`.

For example:

```
UID  PART_ID  SERV_DATE   SERV_REMARK  
1    A0001    11/1/2013   GOOD#1  
2    A0001    11/13/2013  GOOD#2  
3    A0001    11/25/2013  GOOD#3

UID  PART_ID  DRAWN_DATE  DRAWN_REASON  DRAWN_TO  
1    A0001    11/6/2013   PM            OW601  
2    A0001    11/20/2013  120 PM        OW603  
3    A0001    11/30/2013  REPLACEMENT   OW605
```

Then you can modify your SQL to:

```
SELECT 
  S.PART_ID, SERV_DATE, 
  SERV_REMARK, DRAWN_DATE, 
  DRAWN_REASON, DRAWN_TO
FROM 
  tblService AS S 
RIGHT JOIN 
  tblWithdraw AS W 
ON 
  S.UID=W.UID;
```

This would give the result you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, Solipcyst. Thanks for your reply. I have tested your Answer. It's working in this Question. However, this is not the answer I'm looking for. I have posted a new Question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038812/join-two-tables-and-show-all-records-including-null Please take a look if you are free. Thanks for you time.

Comment: I realize that it may not be the answer to your new question, but if it is an answer to _this_ question, I'd appreciate a mark.  Thanks.